# Implementation of OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

```
void collision_f()
{
    int x;
    long double feq[Q], feq_R[Q], feq_B[Q], feq_force[Q];
    long double mR[Q], mB[Q], meq_R[Q], meq_B[Q];
    long double col_R[Q], col_B[Q];
    
    forces_f();
    
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (x =0; x <NX; x++)
        {
            for (int y =0; y <NY; y++)
            {
                if ( (bnode[x][y] ==0) || (bnode[x][y] ==1) || (bnode[x][y] ==2) )
                {
                    long double uxeq = ux_f[x][y] + Force_x_f[x][y]/rho_f[x][y];
                    long double uyeq = uy_f[x][y] + Force_y_f[x][y]/rho_f[x][y];
                    for (int i =0; i <Q; i++)
                    {
                        feq[i] = feq_R[i] = feq_B[i] = feq_force[i] = 0.0;
                        //equilibrium distribution
                        long double udotc_f = ux_f[x][y]*cx[i] + uy_f[x][y]*cy[i];
                        long double u2_f = pow(ux_f[x][y], 2) + pow(uy_f[x][y], 2);
                        
                        feq[i] = wt[i]*rho_f[x][y]*(1.0 + 3.0*udotc_f + 4.5*pow(udotc_f, 2) - 1.5*u2_f);
                        feq_R[i] = wt[i]*rho_R_f[x][y]*(1.0 + 3.0*udotc_f + 4.5*pow(udotc_f, 2) - 1.5*u2_f);
                        feq_B[i] = wt[i]*rho_B_f[x][y]*(1.0 + 3.0*udotc_f + 4.5*pow(udotc_f, 2) - 1.5*u2_f);
                        
                        long double udotc_force = uxeq*cx[i] + uyeq*cy[i];
                        long double u2_force = pow(uxeq, 2) + pow(uyeq, 2);
                        feq_force[i] = wt[i]*rho_f[x][y]*(1.0 + 3.0*udotc_force + 4.5*pow(udotc_force, 2) - 1.5*u2_force);
                        
                        //printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\n", x, y, i, feq[i], feq_R[i], feq_B[i], feq_force[i]);
                    }
                    
                    //Calculating moments and meq
                    for (int i =0; i <Q; i++)
                    {
                        meq_R[i] = meq_B[i] = mR[i] = mB[i] = 0.0;
                        for (int j =0; j <Q; j++)
                        {
                            mR[i] += M[i][j]*r1[x][y][j];
                            meq_R[i] += M[i][j]*feq_R[j];
                            mB[i] += M[i][j]*b1[x][y][j];
                            meq_B[i] += M[i][j]*feq_B[j];
                            //printf("%d,%d\t%d,%d\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\n", x, y, i, j, mR[i], meq_R[i], mB[i], meq_B[i]);
                        }
                        //printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\n", x, y, i, mR[i], meq_R[i], mB[i], meq_B[i]);
                    }
                    
                    //Collision equation
                    for (int i =0; i <Q; i++)
                    {
                        col_R[i] = col_B[i] = 0.0;
                        for (int j =0; j <Q; j++)
                        {
                            col_R[i] += stmiv_f[x][y][i][j]*(mR[j] - meq_R[j]);
                            col_B[i] += stmiv_f[x][y][i][j]*(mB[j] - meq_B[j]);
                        }
                        long double force = feq_force[i] - feq[i];
                        r2[x][y][i] = r1[x][y][i] - col_R[i];
                        b2[x][y][i] = b1[x][y][i] - col_B[i];
                        f1[x][y][i] = r2[x][y][i] + b2[x][y][i] + force;
                        
                        //Recoloring using d'Ortona's segregation method
                        r2[x][y][i] = (rho_R_f[x][y]/rho_f[x][y]) * (f1[x][y][i] + BETA_LKR*wt[i]*(rho_f[x][y] - rho_R_f[x][y])*(n_x[x][y]*cx[i] + n_y[x][y]*cy[i]));
                        b2[x][y][i] = f1[x][y][i] - r2[x][y][i];
                    }
                    if (rho_R_f[x][y] <=EVAP_LIM*rho_r_f)
                    {
                        for (int i =0; i <Q; i++)
                        {
                            b2[x][y][i] = f1[x][y][i];
                            r2[x][y][i] = 0.0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (rho_B_f[x][y] <=EVAP_LIM*rho_r_f)
                    {
                        for (int i =0; i <Q; i++)
                        {
                            r2[x][y][i] = f1[x][y][i];
                            b2[x][y][i] = 0.0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I am trying to implement `OpenMP` in this function. But I am getting `nan` for `feq_R[Q]` and `-nan` for `meq_R[Q], meq_B[Q]` only for a few combination of `x, y`. Also for each run, the values of `x, y` are different where I get `-nan` kind of solution. I have also checked that `rho_f[x][y]` is not zero for those `x, y`. I have also tried `omp for reduction` for `meq_R[Q], meq_B[Q]` only to be unsuccessful. FYI, the serial code runs without any problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: At very quick first glance, only the loops in `i` are parallelizable. Certainly the loop in `x` isn't, or at least, not in a simple way.

Comment: Hello. To solve your issue you have to assume that `x` values are taken in any order in the loop `for (x =0; x <NX; x++)` because OMP threads will each take a possible `x` value until all iterations are done. If in any of the inner loop you have a dependency on another loop result (eg `x == 4` calculation depends on `x == 3`) then your code will not work as expected.

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle All the calculations are local to position `x, y`. The problem I am facing is parallelizing the `i` and `j` loops.

Comment: The first big problem is that openmp probably takes feq, feq_R, feq_B, feq_force as shared, so you have race conditions. For this reason you should add "default(none)" to your pragma and then define what is shared, private, firstprivate, lastprivate, etc

Comment: E. g. "private(feq, feq_R, feq_B, feq_force)" as far as I can see.

Comment: Same thing for everything else that only depends on i and is written to. The stuff that depends on x should be shared.

Comment: @Paul By making those 1D arrays private, it actually worked. Thanks for the help.